# 2 Save calls in one model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Can anyone explain to me why CakePHP wil only create one row when I execute the following code

```
$this->Adresses->save(array('Contact_ID' => $ClientID, 'Type' => 1, 'Addressline_1' =>    $_POST['Straat'], 'House_Number' => $_POST['Huisnummer'], 'Postal_Code' => $_POST['Postcode'], 'City' => $_POST['Woonplaats'], 'Country' => 'NL'));

$this->Adresses->save(array('Contact_ID' => $ClientID, 'Type' => 2, 'Addressline_1' => $_POST['F_Straat'], 'House_Number' => $_POST['F_Huisnummer'], 'Postal_Code' => $_POST['F_Postcode'], 'City' => $_POST['F_Woonplaats'], 'Country' => 'NL'));
```

I just want it to make 2 seperate rows in the same table

EDIT:

After I followed the solutions below and changed te code to this:

```
$this->Adresses->create();

$this->Adresses->save(array('Contact_ID' => $ClientID, 'Type' => 1, 'Addressline_1' =>   $_POST['Straat'], 'House_Number' => $_POST['Huisnummer'], 'Postal_Code' => $_POST['Postcode'], 'City' => $_POST['Woonplaats'], 'Country' => 'NL'));

$this->Adresses->create();

$this->Adresses->save(array('Contact_ID' => $ClientID, 'Type' => 2, 'Addressline_1' => $_POST['F_Straat'], 'House_Number' => $_POST['F_Huisnummer'], 'Postal_Code' => $_POST['F_Postcode'], 'City' => $_POST['F_Woonplaats'], 'Country' => 'NL'));
```

it saves to seperate rows but for some reason the column type is in both rows '1'. How is this possible?

Comment: is your table primary key AUTO_INCREMENT set?

Comment: for starters I would stick to conventions: lower_case_underscored_field_names. although that should not be the source of the problem

Comment: I updated the cakephp docs to outline the create() as necessary before each save call here. therefore you probably selected the wrong (or at least just half true) answer as correct :) https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `create` method after first `save` method
eg :-

```
$this->Adresses->save(array('Contact_ID' => $ClientID, 'Type' => 1, 'Addressline_1' =>    $_POST['Straat'], 'House_Number' => $_POST['Huisnummer'], 'Postal_Code' => $_POST['Postcode'], 'City' => $_POST['Woonplaats'], 'Country' => 'NL'));

$this->Adresses->create();

$this->Adresses->save(array('Contact_ID' => $ClientID, 'Type' => 2, 'Addressline_1' => $_POST['F_Straat'], 'House_Number' => $_POST['F_Huisnummer'], 'Postal_Code' => $_POST['F_Postcode'], 'City' => $_POST['F_Woonplaats'], 'Country' => 'NL'));
```

Comment: nope, you should always call create() first. you never know if you saved prior to the first call (in beforeFilter etc) which then will screw up your code again. so never ever forget create() before any inserting save call.

Comment: you should call `create` method before each calling of `save` method

Comment: If `save` method is calling first time there is no need of calling `create` method, if you are calling `save` method after a `save` method call, you should use `create` method

Comment: did you not read my comment? you cannot possible know if it is the first time. in any callback (beforeFilter e.g.) you could at some point store information prior to the controller action execution. since you cannot be sure about whether it is the first time you need to always include create() to be on the safe side here. even if the code works right now, it can break with the addition of any such callback save. so why creating faulty apps if you can avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

because you forgot one of the most basic things when creating new records: always call create() first:

```
 $this->Adresses->create();
 $this->Adresses->save($data);
```

otherwise the second call will use the id from the first one. so never forget create() when creating a new record (instead of updating existing ones).

Comment: doc update to clarify this further for other beginners: https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/385